# Mercurial, Apache, Windows, mod_auth_sspi and hg push

Tags: windows, apache, mercurial

I'm playing with Mercurial 1.6 under Apache 2.2.15 on a Windows box under a Windows domain, running as a central repo server to which select people will have commit permissions.

I'm trying to restrict access to Mercurial by restricting access to Apache's /cgi-bin/ to select users via sspi_auth_module.

If I browse to the repo page with sspi_auth_module enforcing restrictions on /cgi-bin/ I'm prompted for a username and password, which is accepted and everything works fine.

If I try to use the CLI "hg push" to commit from my local repo to the server, from the command-line, the command terminates very quickly with the message:

```
abort: authorization failed
```

If I remove /cgi-bin/ restrictions, pushing works.

The relevant section of httpd.conf: (names redacted)

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthName "XXXXXX"
AuthType SSPI
SSPIAuth On
SSPIAuthoritative On
SSPIOmitDomain On
Require user "xxxxxx"
</Directory>
```

The relevant section of my hgweb.config file (repositories stored in C:/Hg)

```
[collections]
C:/Hg = C:/Hg

[web]
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false
allow_archive = bz2 gz zip
```

I'd like to let the domain controller worry about authentication (to me, it's better than having everyone memorize extra passwords!) - is this a viable approach?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I suspect that part of the issue was that I did not have **SSPIDomain** specified (mistaking it for AuthName ... duh)

Anyway, the following in httpd.conf did the trick: (the ScriptAlias directive was there from the beginning, BTW)

```
ScriptAlias /hg "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi"

<Location /hg>
AuthName "Mercurial Authentication"
AuthType SSPI
SSPIAuth On
SSPIAuthoritative On
SSPIDomain XXXXXX
SSPIOmitDomain On     
SSPIOfferBasic On 
SSPIBasicPreferred Off
Require user "xxxxxx"
</Location>
```

I removed myself as a required user, was prompted for username and password, and could not authenticate. I then added myself back and was able to authenticate OK.

Thanks for looking!